# Plan to reduce or remove [swr] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

I'm currently of the opinion that [swr](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swr) is a (mildly) bad tag.

The reason is that it *rarely* describes what the question is actually about; rather, the asker has some other problem and a high SWR reading is evidence of the problem. It's like tagging an electronics question with "voltage" — it usually isn't specific enough.

Therefore, I — have already retagged a bunch of [swr](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swr) questions, and created two new tags:

- [impedance-matching](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impedance-matching) for questions like [how to make a 3-way coax splitter](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/3-way-coax-split-impedance-match), or in general impedance matching networks and the need for matching.

  - We already have [antenna-tuner](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna-tuner) for adjustable matching networks.
- [swr-meter](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swr-meter) for questions like [how a crossed-needle display works](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/953/what-is-the-point-of-a-swr-power-meter-where-the-needles-cross-over-each-other).

I'd like to eliminate the tag entirely (perhaps arrange so that we have [swr-mismatch](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swr-mismatch) → [impedance-matching](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impedance-matching) for the benefit of tag completion) but I am less certain that this is a good idea, so speak up if you have a proposal or argument on the subject.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is now complete. All questions have been retagged, and [vswr](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vswr) and [swr](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swr) (formerly synonyms) are now synonyms of [impedance-matching](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impedance-matching).